How to use the Autodesk Tandem Viewer in an app that already initializes the Autodesk Viewer?
I have an app that successfully initializes and uses the Autodesk Viewer. Now, I want to add the Autodesk Tandem Viewer.
Here is the initialization for the Autodesk Viewer:
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({
  env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
  api: this.bEmea ? 'streamingV2_EU' : 'streamingV2',
  getAccessToken: accessToken
}, fnCallback);

I tried initializing the Tandem Viewer like this:
const options = {
  env: 'DtProduction',
  api: 'dt',
  productId: 'Digital Twins', 
  corsWorker: true,
  accessToken: accessToken
};

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, fnCallback);

However, I get the following error in the console:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ROOT')
The error originates from the following code in webpack://LMV/src/envinit.js:
while options is 'DtViewer'
export function initializeServiceEndPoints(options) {

    // Get endpoint.
    var endp = options.endpoint;
    if (!endp) {
        var config = EnvironmentConfigurations[getEnv()];
        endp = config['ROOT'];
    }
}

Here is the full call stack of the error:
at _a (envinit.js:432:33)
at Object.Ma [as Initializer] (envinit.js:762:23)
at eval (Component.js?eval:159:26)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at c._initViewer [as initViewer] (Component.js?eval:150:14)
at eval (Component.js?eval:106:21)

Is it possible to use the Tandem Viewer in an app that already initializes the Autodesk Viewer? If yes, how should the options be configured correctly?
I have already reviewed this answer and ensured in my code that the JavaScript files for the Viewer are loaded only once.

Can you provide more details about your scenario, pls? Are you trying to use both APS Viewer and Tandem Viewer side by side, pls?

Both APS and Tandem Viewers don't need to be visible simultaneously.
We use the SAP Fiori Launchpad for our apps.
In the first scenario: If we start App A, which uses the Autodesk Viewer, we cannot start App B, which uses the Tandem Viewer, after closing App A.
In a second scenario, we want to switch between the viewers but not display them at the same time.
Our main interests are: Tandem Views, Filter configurations, and Inventory Table settings.
It might help if we could unload the viewer properly after usage to avoid conflicts when switching between viewers.

There isn't currently easy solution because viewer (both APS Viewer and Tandem Viewer) are polluting global namespace. There can be some options:

set USE_LMV_APP_NAMESPACES to true and define own namespace using LMV_APP_NAMESPACE, for example:

<script>
  window.USE_LMV_APP_NAMESPACES = true;
  window.LMV_APP_NAMESPACE = 'myApp';
</script>

This should be set before loading first viewer script. Note this option wasn't thoroughly tested and may have some limitations.

Could you possibly use separate window for each viewer?

